# Mistake where it shouldn't be

Tags: random

```
function generateRandomString($minlen = 7, $maxlen = 10, $randomCase = 0) {
    $length = rand($minlen, $maxlen);
    $symbols = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F',
        'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L',
        'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'S',
        'T', 'U', 'V', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
        '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',
        '7', '8', '9', '0');
    $string = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $index = rand(0, strlen($symbols) - 1);
        $symbol = $symbols[$index];
        if ($randomCase)
            $symbol = (rand(0, 1)) ? strtolower($symbol) : $symbol;
        $string .= $symbol;
    }
    return $string;
```

Where can there be an error in the code?

Comment: Is this any language in particular?  Maybe one that doesn't require balanced braces?

Comment: Welcome drednoyd. Please add the tag for the language you are using, state what the program is expected to do, and provide the error message.